# How do I connect HTML page to MongoDB?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I am using node.js. I have connected node.js to my MongoDB database. I would like to know how to connect the HTML page to node.js?

Comment: Use an engine like Swig or Jade

Answer (score -2):

Connecting HTML to MongoDB like any other database needs a server-side solution. In your server-side whether its PHP, Node.js or ASP connect to DB, Get all data you need and render HTML page subsequently.